# Closed form for particular power series $\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{a^kk^y}{(Tk+b)!}$.

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, closed-form

A (senior) acquaintance of mine was trying, unsuccesfully, to find a closed expressions for

> $$\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{a^kk^y}{(Tk+b)!}$$

where $a\neq0$, and $y$, $b$ and $T$ are positive integers.

Except for the trivial special cases, is such a thing known? Any help or pointers toward the literature would be appreciated.

Comment: For $T=2$ you will get hyperbolic cos & sin. Closed forms for other values of $T$ can probably be expressed as linear combinations of exponentials of roots of unity times $a$. Differentiate these if you want non trivial value for $y$.

Comment: First, solve this for$T=1, b=0$. This might be easier if you use$\prod_{j=0}^{y-1}(y+j)$ instead of$y^k$. Then use multisection of series.

Answer (score 0):

We have the [Mittag-Leffler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_function),

$$E_{\alpha,\beta}(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{z^k\over\Gamma(\alpha k+\beta)}$$

Or,

$$E_{T,b+1}(e^t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{e^{kt}\over(Tk+b)!}$$

And by repeated differentiation:

$${\partial^y\over\partial^yt}E_{T,b+1}(e^t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{e^{kt}k^y\over(Tk+b)!}$$

And finally:

> $${\partial^y\over\partial^yt}E_{T,b+1}(e^t)\bigg|_{a=e^t}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{a^kk^y\over(Tk+b)!}$$

Comment: @user90369 You really can't expect something really nice from these sorts of problems sometimes, and so even if I don't think my solution could qualify as "closed form", it does provide a method to which one could find closed forms, given $T$ and $b$.

Comment: Perhaps. It really comes down to evaluating $\sum{a^k\over(Tk+b)!}$, which is given in your answer. By apply [Faa di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula)

Comment: That's a good hint for the OP. --- I know this formula but not under the name *Faà di Bruno*. Thanks!